# How to convert this in a JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm very new on this and I isn't a pro on this issues!

I'm just here for request for your help because I know this community is the best for this problems!

Actually I'm using a software called "Bulk Rename Utility", it works for bulk rename files with a very useful interface, one of them is the RegEx option where you can rename files thanks to the regular expresion lenguage.

I was wonder if I can convert this code in a JavaScript code, this is because I need to modify various parameters and it could be better if I can use a JavaScript code.

As I told you, I'm very new on this. After checking some videos I learned how to use the RegEx option in this program and the codes I got was:

In the "Match" field of the program I write: `(.*) 10-1[A-Z] (.*)`.

In the "Replace" filed of the program I write: \1_REF_\2

A then, it do the magic!

As I said, I want to know how I can convert this code to a JavaScript code because I have a lot of this codes and I want just one whole code to make a bulk process.

Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```js
const str = 'abc 10-1G def';
const outputStr = str.replace(/(.*) 10-1[A-Z] (.*)/, '$1REF$2');
console.log(outputStr);
```

You just need to put `$1`/`$2` in place of the captured groups you want in the replaced string.

To insert code, you can put the code between backticks (`) and you'll be able to type *s normally.